# Discount code.. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: c++

This code is designed to give the final price of an item based off of the customers quantity. I have already added in the equations but when it is ran it the discount and the final price are not evaluating correctly. If someone knows where I went wrong in the pseudocode, it would be very helpful.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

    // Variables
    double Retail, quantity, discount1, discount2, discount3, discount4, TotalCost1, TotalCost2, TotalCost3, TotalCost4;
    Retail = 99;
    quantity = 0;
    discount1 = (quantity * Retail) * .20;
    discount2 = (quantity * Retail) * .30;
    discount3 = (quantity * Retail) * .40;
    discount4 = (quantity * Retail) * .50;
    TotalCost1 = quantity - discount1;
    TotalCost2 = quantity - discount2;
    TotalCost3 = quantity - discount3;
    TotalCost4 = quantity - discount4;

    //Equations
    cout << "Please enter the quantity of items you would like to purchase: " << endl;
    cin >> quantity;
    cout << "The number of items being purchased is: " << quantity << endl;

    if (quantity <= 19) {
        cout << "Your final price is: " << discount1 << endl;
    }
    if (quantity >= 20) {
        cout << "Your final price is: " << discount2 << endl;
    }
    if (quantity >= 50) {
        cout << "Your final price is: " << discount3 << endl;
    }
    if (quantity >= 100) {
        cout << "Your final price is: " << discount4 << endl;
    }




        system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about you what mean by "it's not running correctly."  Also take a look at [mcve]. you have the code, you just need to be more detailed about the specific issue you are facing.

Comment: Post real code and the specific errors you are getting.

Comment: What is `if (quantity <= 19, discount1)` for?

Comment: quantity is 0 when you do your discount calculations. You need to probably take in the quantity before doing the discount equations.

Comment: If the amount of items is less than or equal to 19 items then the discount applied is 20%

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting in here when the program is being run it is not calculating the final price it is just giving me the amount of items and the cout response related to the quantity. It not applying the discount and displaying the final price.

Comment: `discount1 = (quantity * Retail) * .20;`is evaluated immediately,  You have to read the quantity first.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just that you're quantity isn't defined as being anything except 0 before your calculate the discounts?  I moved the read of your purchase before the calculations and got better results (using online compiler).

```
double Retail, quantity, discount1, discount2, discount3, discount4, TotalCost1, TotalCost2, TotalCost3, TotalCost4;
Retail = 99;
quantity = 0;

//Equations
cout << "Please enter the quantity of items you would like to purchase: " << endl;
cin >> quantity;
cout << "The number of items being purchased is: " << quantity << endl;

discount1 = (quantity * Retail) * .20;
discount2 = (quantity * Retail) * .30;
discount3 = (quantity * Retail) * .40;
discount4 = (quantity * Retail) * .50;
TotalCost1 = quantity - discount1;
TotalCost2 = quantity - discount2;
TotalCost3 = quantity - discount3;
TotalCost4 = quantity - discount4;


if (quantity <= 19) {
    cout << "Your final price is: " << discount1 << endl;
}
if (quantity >= 20) {
    cout << "Your final price is: " << discount2 << endl;
}
if (quantity >= 50) {
    cout << "Your final price is: " << discount3 << endl;
}
if (quantity >= 100) {
    cout << "Your final price is: " << discount4 << endl;
}


Please enter the quantity of items you would like to purchase: 
The number of items being purchased is: 19
Your final price is: 376.2
```

Comment: `if(quantity <= 19, discount1)` is almost certainly another problem.

Comment: I suggested an edit of this to remove the , discount1.

Comment: Done. Honestly c++ isn't my strongest skill. Made me read up on my c++ comma operator in an if statement.